# Why are Republicans more likely to support keeping the filibuster than Democrats in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, senate, republican-party, filibuster

> Most Democrats say they'd end it, as a general matter, according to a
> CBS News poll from Jan. 2022. Two-thirds of Republicans say they'd
> keep it.
>
> But the partisan split appears strongly connected to more immediate
> policy concerns. Of the Democrats who feel it's very important to pass
> a federal voting rights bill, an even higher portion, seven in 10,
> would generally end the filibuster. That, of course, is the measure
> over which some Democratic leaders have discussed ending it.
>
> President Joe Biden has called on the Senate to make an exception to
> its filibuster rules to allow Congress to codify abortion protections
> and privacy rights previously afforded under Roe v. Wade.

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/filibuster-senate-what-is-it-how-does-it-work/

According to the article, two-thirds of the Republicans want to keep the filibuster while the majority of Democrats want to end it. Is there a political reason why a majority of Republicans want to keep it when it prevents work from getting done in the Senate? What are the possible reasons for this wide gap in opinion between the two political parties?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While there is truth to the [James K answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/85928), there's some power dynamics at play.

The Senate has been steadily chipping away at the Filibuster using the so-called [Nuclear option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option) to change Senate rules with a simple majority vote

- Democrats removed it for non-SCOTUS judicial nominees and cabinet positions in 2013
- Republicans removed it for SCOTUS nominees in 2017

All that remains now is the legislative filibuster. Republicans could have removed it in 2017-2019 (held both chambers, the House and the Presidency). Why didn't they? [Mostly because the Filibuster isn't as large an impediment to conservative goals](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/analysis-opinion/why-mitch-mcconnell-will-keep-legislative-filibuster)

> Now the game is “reconciliation.” Filibusters aren’t allowed under
> reconciliation, so all it takes for passage is 51 votes. But
> reconciliation also limits debate  and the type of amendments that can
> be offered – precisely the kind of restrictions Senators from both
> parties are often reluctant to accept. It takes foresight and advanced
> parliamentary maneuvering to go the reconciliation route. But it’s
> easier than breaking a filibuster. Obamacare passed via
> reconciliation. So did COBRA in 1986 and the Children’s Health
> Insurance Program in 1997. The Reagan and Bush tax cuts passed that
> way too. Although reconciliation was created in 1974, it wasn’t used
> until 1980. Overall, Congress has used reconciliation 25 times.
>
> McConnell has other filibuster-busting tools at his disposal: fast
> track authority for trade agreements, and the Congressional Review Act
> which allows Congress to overturn federal agency rules. Under fast
> track, the Senate can approve international trade deals without having
> to worry about a filibuster. And the Congressional Review Act, lets
> the Senate nullify certain federal agency rules filibuster-free.
> Before this year, the Review Act had been used only once. Thus far in
> 2017, it has been used 13 times, overturning Obama-era regulations on
> matters such as privacy protections for broadband users, limits on gun
> purchases by the mentally ill, and disclosure requirements for oil
> company payments to foreign governments.

Democrats already use these tools to get some of their priorities as well (such as the [Inflation Reduction Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_Reduction_Act), passed via Reconciliation).

#### Democrats are trying to pass larger-scale legislation

There have been several large pieces of legislation introduced in the 2021-2023 Congress where Democrats tried (and failed) to get them through because of the Filibuster

- The [Freedom to Vote Act](https://www.capito.senate.gov/news/in-the-news/us-senate-democrats-fail-to-pass-voting-legislation-change-filibuster), which would have nationalized several parts of the election code and swept away most Republican voting laws
- The [Judiciary Act of 2023](https://www.democracydocket.com/news-alerts/democrats-introduce-bill-to-expand-u-s-supreme-court/) would have added four seats to the Supreme Court, all picked by President Biden
- [Medicare for All](https://www.businessinsider.com/alexandria-ocasio-cortez-medicare-for-all-progressives-senate-filibuster-2023-4) would have expanded Medicare (taxpayer medical coverage for US citizens 65 and older) to all US citizens.

Answer (score 36):

The filibuster benefits the minority party, especially when that party doesn't control the Whitehouse.  So when there is a Democratic party president, and a Democratic majority in the Senate, the the filibuster benefits the Republican party.  It is no surprise, therefore that Republicans support it now, and Democrats would get rid of it.

But wait around a few years until the Democrats are in a minority and are using the filibuster to block Republican legislation, and you will find that the opinion on the filibuster will switch.

As the Democratic party has an electoral disadvantage in the Senate (small states are rural states, and they hold a majority of the electorate) in the long term, the filibuster benefits the Democratic party.  This is why Democratic legislators are loathe to invoke the "nuclear option" to get laws passed.  They fear such a decision would leave them unable to block future Republican legislation.

In a sense, it doesn't "prevent the Senate from doing business", it is "working as intended".  The point being that if you want to make laws in the USA you need to either have overwhelming support from the voters, or work on a bill that has sufficient bi-partisan support.  And if you can't get bipartisan support, *you should not make new laws*. This assumption that laws should not be passed may be surprising, but it is how the US political system works.

Comment: While this seems somewhat plausible this would be a lot more credible with some source from the past when the Republicans were in power. I'm sure this isn't the first time ending the filibuster was discussed but if these discussion only happen when the Democrats are in power I would consider absence of evidence as evidence of absence in this case.

Comment: "working as intended" is kind of debatable, I'd say. Was the filibuster always used as a means to indefinitely block legislation that doesn't have a super-majority behind it? Or maybe this role has evolved over time. I would mostly argue that the filibuster protects the status quo, it benefits whoever doesn't want things to change. This can be good or bad and maybe it was intended, or maybe it wasn't or maybe it was intended but not that strongly. Politics 150 years ago was much more dynamic than today (do we invade Mexico, do we buy Cuba, should California be a territory or a state, ...).

Comment: Small states don’t hold a majority of the electorate. The largest nine states between them have a majority of the population of the US. Small states have a majority of the _Senators_ — the other 41 states have 49% of the population, but 82% of the Senators.

Comment: If followers of both parties had different views on whether what you describe in the last paragraph is good or bad then that could also explain different opinions on filibusters, independent of who currently has a majority in which body.

Comment: Is it "working as intended" when significant majorities of the population want stricter gun control and believe abortion should be mostly legal, but it's unlikely either could get past a fillibuster?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution it's an obvious part of the senate procedures codified by Jefferson in 1796 and in continuous use since. It's also fully aligned with the traditional role of the senate ("the dish into which the hot passions of the house can be poured to cool").

Comment: I would question that it is working as intended when you just have to say that you are going to filibuster something but don’t have to actually filibuster it like you do at the state level. It is this way because of overuse of the filibuster and the change made it worse.

Comment: @Barmar  Yes "Working as intended" is not "working how I want".  It isn't a democracy and doesn't claim to be.  It is intended to prevent legislation. Where I come from the government is free to legislate, but the US system  is *designed* to make it very hard for federal laws to be passed.  My own opinions on how broken this is are irrelevant - this level of brokenness is intended by the rules of the senate.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we need to know *who* intended this. The fillibuster is just a rule the Senate created for themselves, it's not enshrined in the Constitution.

Comment: But the right of the Senate to create their own rules is enshrined.

Comment: Just because they have the right to create their own rules doesn't mean it was intended for a single person to be able to prevent a bill from getting a vote needing 51(or 50 with vp tie breaker) to pass by requiring 60 votes to end the filibuster.  There is a reason why a filibuster at the state level requires the person/persons doing the filibuster to talk for the entire time of the filibuster.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it was intended for.  The Constitution, over and over again, puts up roadblocks in the way of the creation of federal laws, making it deliberately difficult to pass anything without broad consensus.  The idea is that if you can't get a consensus agreement that this idea should apply to the entire country, then it probably shouldn't. If you like the idea, get it passed as a local law in your own jurisdiction, where it's a lot easier to do, but don't try to impose it on the entire rest of the nation if there's meaningful levels of disagreement or resistance to your idea.

Comment: I'm surprised to see so many people debate the "working as intended" part of the answer without bringing up the history. It's generally thought that the filibuster was accidently introduced into the Senate when they were cleaning up their rules in 1805. This is why the House doesn't have the filibuster. The filibuster wasn't even used for decades after the change. https://www.brookings.edu/articles/senate-filibuster-was-created-by-mistake/

Comment: You say: "small states are rural states, and they hold a majority of the electorate," but this is incorrect. There are a number of small, densely populated states in the northeast. Despite common perception, there isn't a huge political bias in the senate seats.